# Cannot build native image with Quarkus on Win10

Tags: java, windows, native, quarkus, graalvm

- GraalVM: 19.3.1

  - Java: 11.0.5
  - OS: Win10 pro
  - Quarkus: 1.2.0.Final
  - repo: https://github.com/tdevilleduc/code-with-quarkus.git

I'm working currently on Quarkus, and i've manage to build a native image with -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker parameter
I want now to make the same without this parameter

I started back from [generating my application](https://code.quarkus.io/) and i'm following [building native image tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image)
Problem : I get this error message

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Final:build (default) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: c:\Users\devil\Documents\repository\code-with-quarkus\target\code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from c:\Users\devil\Documents\repository\code-with-quarkus\target\code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version dev
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] C:\Program Files\Tools\graalvm\graalvm-ce-java11-19.3.1\bin\native-image.cmd -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:+JNI -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
Warning: the '=' character in program arguments is not fully supported.
Make sure that command line arguments using it are wrapped in double quotes.
Example:
"--vm.Dfoo=bar"

Error: Unknown arguments: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager, io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory, true, DISABLED, 1, com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime, 0, http, code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.930 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-12T21:51:49+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Final:build (default) on project code-with-quarkus: Failed to build a runnable JAR: Failed to augment application classes: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
```

I've try to add all theses args in quarkus.native.additional-build-args in application.properties but it didn't change at all

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not supported yet by graalvm.